# How to to 0/1 subsetting in Theano?

Tags: python, syntax, subset, theano, matrix-indexing

The objective is to obtain the subset of an array of elements through values provided in another array.

```python
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

a = T.vector('X', dtype='int64')
b = T.vector('Y', dtype='int64')
c = a[b]
g = function([a,b],c)

x = np.array([5,3,2,3,4,6], dtype=int)
y = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1], dtype=int)
print g(x,y)
```

This prints

```
[5 5 3 5 5 3]
```

instead of

```
[2 6]
```

How do I get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `nonzero()` function.

Example in your case:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

a = T.vector('X', dtype='int64')
b = T.vector('Y', dtype='int64')
c = a[b.nonzero()]
g = function([a,b],c)

x = np.array([5,3,2,3,4,6], dtype=int)
y = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1], dtype=int)
print g(x,y)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Wonderful! Just what I was looking for! Usually, I'll use `astype(bool)` for `numpy` arrays, but was worried as I couldn't do this for tensors. I also just observed that `nonzero()` works for `numpy` too. Thanks a bunch. This problem was driving me crazy.